# Stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am facing an issue with a stored procedures in C#, I am getting this error :

> *Procedure or function myQSProcedure_Delete has too many arguments
>   specified.*

I am unable to resolve this. kindly help me.

Code is as follows.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myQSProcedure_Delete] 
@Id int
AS
BEGIN
Delete From tblfb where Id = @Id
End
```

My C# code is:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
DataTable dtDelete = (DataTable)ViewState["dtDelete"];
dtDelete.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["Id"].ToString(),
dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["name"].ToString(), dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["session"].ToString(),
dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["gender"].ToString(), dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["email"].ToString(),
dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["address"].ToString(), dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["priority"].ToString(),       
dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["comments"].ToString());
ViewState["dtDelete"] = dtDelete;
dt.Rows[e.RowIndex].Delete();
dt.AcceptChanges();
if (dt.Rows.Count < 1)
dt.Rows.Add(null, "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
ViewState["dt"] = dt;
if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString().Equals(""))
    {
        GridView1.Rows[0].Visible = false;
    }
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("data source=Burhan\\SQLEXPRESS;database=mydb;integrated security=true");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("myQSProcedure_Delete", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  foreach (DataRow row in dtDelete.Rows)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id",row[0]));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
   conn.Close();
   GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    ViewState["dt"] = dt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also add the parameter once and assign it values n times, as follows:

```
  using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("myQSProcedure_Delete", conn))
  {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id",SqlDbType.Int);
      foreach (DataRow row in dtDelete.Rows)
      {
          cmd.Parameters["@Id"].Value = row[0];
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
  }
```

Comment: Well Mahdi problem is solved but another problem is there which is the data is being deleted from viewstate but not from actual database do u knw something about this ?

Comment: And another problem is also there.. When i click on first index it delets from viewstate not from database but when i click on the second index it gives me an error .. There is no Row at position 1

Comment: Kindly give me some suggestions so i can get out of this

Comment: @BurhanMughal have you tried Tracing the code to see if it gets to the `cmd.ExecureNonQuery()` or not?

Comment: well in case of first index it loops through the whole Code but in case of second index it got stuck at

Comment: dtDelete.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["Id"].ToString(), dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["name"].ToString(), dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["session"].ToString(), dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["gender"].ToString(), dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["email"].ToString(), dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["address"].ToString(), dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["priority"].ToString(), dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["comments"].ToString());

Comment: can u suggess me solution '

Comment: You've done something wrong, trace the code and check the count of items in your datasets, I guess you have deleted a row and after that you are trying to retrieve the row which does not exist any more, check it and let me know.

Comment: DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"]; DataTable dtDelete = (DataTable)ViewState["dtDelete"]; dtDelete.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["Id"].ToString(), dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["name"].ToString(); ViewState["dtDelete"] = dtDelete; dt.Rows[e.RowIndex].Delete(); dt.AcceptChanges(); if (dt.Rows.Count < 1) dt.Rows.Add(null, "",); GridView1.DataSource = dt; GridView1.DataBind(); ViewState["dt"] = dt; –

Comment: Just look at this i have saved that particular row before deleting it .. But still getting porblem

Comment: in Trace after adding the particular row to `dtDelete` how many rows does `dtDelete` have?

Comment: Well i have solved all the problem mentioned above but still have a problem :P i.e. When i delete on record it deletes from viewstate and DB as well but at the same time when i deletes the second record it Gives the Error .. Two many Arguments in Store Proceduer .. When i check that how many records dtDelete have I come to know that there are two rrecords .. Now to remove this error ??

Comment: Yes i have resolved all the Problems Thanks To Allah and U Guys. Thank You very much

Comment: Hellow Mahdi I need some help .. R u free ??

Comment: Hello @BurhanMughal Yes I'm here, take a shot.

Comment: Ok Mahdi As i am also working in sencha touch do u have any knowledge about sencha touch javascript framework ?

Comment: No Dear I've no experience on javascript

Comment: Ok no problem thanx for Your positive response

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the command is retaining it's parameters as you loop through the rows. You should create a new command during each iteration:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtDelete.Rows)
{
  using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("myQSProcedure_Delete", conn)
  {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id",row[0]));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Comment: To add, it would better if the SqlCommand was wrapped within a using block to dispose resources.

Comment: @ryadavilli I prefer your solution actually, no need to new-up a new command in each iteration.

Comment: Well it is working fine i.e. the error is removed but still have a prblem i.e. it is deleting data from viewstate but not from actual database kindly help to get out of this..

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies in the fact that you add a new parameter everytime you loop through. Try the below code instead.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("myQSProcedure_Delete", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    foreach (DataRow row in dtDelete.Rows)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id",row[0]));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: but still have a problem that is It deletes the data from gridView i.e. from viewstate but not deleting actually i.e. from database .. Do u knw something about this ?

Comment: Do you mean it is getting removed from the view but the actual query is not deleting the data from the DB ?

Comment: And i am also facing another problem Bro i.e. i can insert multiple rows in viewstate and can insert at at a time .. it is working fine.. But when i click delete from row 0 it is deleting from viewstate and not DB but when i click on the row1 it gives me an error i.e. There is no row at position 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure only expects a single int as parameters and you are possibly sending a whole bunch.

You need to call the procedure individually for each row you want to delete and clear the parameters.